# What is the Clifford gates selection probability distribution used in the generation of randomized benchmarking circuits?

Tags: qiskit, programming, random-quantum-circuit, randomised-benchmarking

I've read that in standard randomized benchmarking implementations the random quantum circuits are generated through random gate selection from a uniformly distributed Clifford set of either 1 or 2-qubit gates i.e. {H, X, Y, Z, S, T} and {iSWAP, CZ}, however the circuits generated using [`randomized_benchmarking_seq`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.ignis.verification.randomized_benchmarking_seq.html) do not seem to follow this for the following reasons:

1. Random circuits do **NOT** contain T, iSWAP and CZ gates
2. Random circuits do contain CX gates
3. There does not appear to be a uniform distribution in gate selection, for example gates H and S gates appear more frequently than X, Y, Z and CX gates

Is this observation correct? and if so what is the actual distribution for `randomized_benchmarking_seq`? and how can uniformly distributed random circuits be generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random Clifford elements are generated using the following function:

https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.random_clifford.html

Then they are synthesized into basic gates (CX, S, Sdg, H, Paulis) using the following function:

https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Clifford.to_circuit.html#qiskit.quantum_info.Clifford.to_circuit

This is based on the following paper:

S. Bravyi and D. Maslov, Hadamard-free circuits expose the structure of the Clifford group. https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.09412

For a simpler explanation on the structure of the 1-qubit and 2-qubit Clifford groups see the following tutorial:

https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-community-tutorials/blob/master/terra/qis_adv/Clifford_Group.ipynb